# construct url in angularjs directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I made a directive for automatically add links for a html validation, like that :

```
.directive('validationhtml', function($rootScope, $location) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        template: '<a href="" data-ng-click="createTab(getUrl(), $event);" title="validation html">validation html</a>',
        controller: function($scope, $location) {
            $scope.getUrl = function() {
                var url = 'http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=' + $location.path;
                console.log(url);
                return url;
            }
        }
    };
})
```

`createTab();` is a function in rootscope, and correctly executed (new tab), but `getUrl();` have a problem: the url is not good, in the return i have this

```
http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=function (c){if(B(c))return this[b];this[b]=a(c);this.$$compose();return this}
```

what's wrong ?

Answer (score 1):

It should be `location.path()`.

Comment: thks, but now there is 'http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=' and a blank, even with $sce

Comment: `$location.path()` return the path of your current page (ex. for `www.example.com/foo/bar` it returns `foo/bar`). If you use it on a page without path (ex. `www.example.com`) the result will be an empty string. If you want to retrieve the full URL of your page you must use `$location.absUrl()`.

Answer (score 1):

$location `path` is a function:

```
var url = 'http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=' + $location.path();
```

Comment: thks, but now there is 'http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=' and a blank, even with $sce

Comment: How about `$location.absUrl();` is that empty, too?